# How to get the category title in a post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, get, categories

Say I have a post called Hello World in Wordpress and I'm directly viewing this page, how would I go about finding the category of "Hello World" and displaying it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_category) like this:

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
} 
?>
```

It returns a list because a post can have more than one category.

[The documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_category) also explains how to do this from outside the loop.

Answer (score 25):

You can use

```
<?php the_category(', '); ?>
```

which would output them in a comma separated list.

You can also do the same for tags as well:

```
<?php the_tags('<em>:</em>', ', ', ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the category id, category link and category name in wordpress using php, you can use below code:

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');

$category_link = get_category_link($cat_id);

$category_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);

echo $category_name; // It will print your category name
```