# $_GET and permalink issue

Tags: php, get, permalinks

I have a permalink like so `/products-page/custom/test-product/`

the custom is my products category, test-product is the product name and products-page is the page name.

In php I am trying to GET the category name like so

```
if($_GET['wpsc_product_category'] == "Custom"){ 
//do something
}
```

but the code above does not work...is there away to grab the custom with get even thought my permalink looks weird?

Comment: try `custom` small letter, would it be helpful?

Comment: Is this wordpress-related?

Comment: Are you using mod-rewrite, or any frameworks?

Comment: this is wordpress related yes Josh

Comment: Basically I am trying to get the category name (using WP-Ecommerce)

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945906/how-to-get-the-category-title-in-a-post-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change around some stuff in .htaccess. $_GET is designed with permalinks like `index.php?wpsc_product_category=Custom` and such. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462359/htaccess-replace-rewrite-get-variables-in-php-url) post.

Answer (score 0):

Original Answer: [How to get the category title in a post in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945906/how-to-get-the-category-title-in-a-post-in-wordpress)

Haven't tested it.

```
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
  if ( $category->cat_name == 'custom') {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<?php $category = wpsc_the_product_permalink();
                                  $categoryname = explode("/", $category);

                                  if(!$categoryname[4]){ ?>
```

Comment: Clever, but not the best way to do it. A change in the url format (which is easy with wordpress) and this won't work. Better stick with the codex.